# I am not able to open URL using driver.get(“URL”) in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide, browser-automation

I am not able to open a URL using `driver.get(“URL”)` in selenium web driver.

My Firefox version is 53.0.3 and selenium 3.4.0.

**My code is:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("url");
```

**It gives me the below error:**

```
   1496135300464    geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:8753
    1496135301127   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1496135301419   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:671 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:834 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3129 < observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1657: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
JavaScript error: resource://gre/components/SanityTest.js, line 65: NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED: Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIPrefService.savePrefFile]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2570: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm, line 70: NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
```

Comment: Try using geckodriver v0.16.0  It should fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. Instead of "url", it should be some actual url like "http://www.google.com". Also, you might need to provide `moz:firefoxOptions.binary` also. Check the below code for reference -

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //Location where Firefox is installed

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

For more details on the setup, you can refer this article - [Launch Firefox with GeckoDriver](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/)

Comment: i had used actual url only, but for post i have used 'url'. Thank you for your quick reply